# Using document.evaluate in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Using Greasemonkey, I want to automatically click on this element:

```
<input class="autostar {split:2}" type="radio" value="5.0" name="rating-1" style="display:none" f="5">
```

I have written this, but it doesn't work:

```
var result = document.evaluate("//input[@type='radio' and @name='rating-1 and @value='5.0']",
document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);

window.onload = function () {
    result.click();
}
```

Comment: Missing `'` after `rating-1`.

Comment: Also, you can test xpath expressions in the browser console (F12 key): `$x("//div[.='something']")`.

Comment: If you looked in the browser or error consoles, you'd see a very obvious error message or two.